# INNER JOIN result contains duplicated Logins

Tags: sql-server, inner-join

I have table Users which contains columns Login and Phone and I have table GeoPhone which contains columns Mask and Region.

Phone is stored as varchar ("+380981234567"). Mask is stored as varchar ("+38098"). Masks are overlapped, for instance, +380 and +38098.

I need a View that joins Users and GeoPhone tables and assigns Region for each Login by longest matched Mask.

I wrote SQL statement below but result contains duplicated Logins and I do not know how to avoid this:

```
SELECT TOP (5000) 
    Users.Login, Users.Phone, GeoPhone.Region, LEN(GeoPhone.Mask) AS MaskLen
FROM   Users 
INNER JOIN GeoPhone ON LEFT(Users.Phone, LEN(GeoPhone.Mask)) = GeoPhone.Mask
ORDER BY Users.Login, MaskLen DESC
```

Please help to improve it.

Comment: What do you want to do if you have two records in GeoPhone where there's a tie for "longest matched Mask", Also what version of SQL server do you have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do this is to use Cross Apply in SQL 2005 or later.

```
SELECT  
    TOP (5000) Users.Login, 
    Users.Phone, 
    GeoPhone.Region, 
    LEN(GeoPhone.Mask) AS MaskLen 
FROM    Users
    CROSS APPLY
    (
        SELECT  TOP 1 Region,Mask
        FROM    geophone
        WHERE   LEFT (users.phone, Len(geophone.mask)) = geophone.mask 
        ORDER BY
            Len(geophone.mask) DESC
        ) geophone
```

You should note that it only returns one record from geophone. If there are two records in geophone.mask that tie for the length of mask you won't be able to determine which record it will return

Here's a solution that uses MAX() and its realtively portable

```
SELECT TOP (5000) users.LOGIN, 
                  users.phone, 
                  geophone.region, 
                  Len(geophone.mask) AS masklen 
FROM   users 
       INNER JOIN geophone 
         ON LEFT(users.phone, Len(geophone.mask)) = geophone.mask 
       INNER JOIN (SELECT MAX(Len(geophone.mask)) maxlength, 
                          users.phone 
                   FROM   users 
                          INNER JOIN geophone 
                            ON LEFT(users.phone, Len(geophone.mask)) = 
                               geophone.mask 
                   GROUP  BY users.phone) t 
         ON t.phone = users.phone 
            AND t.maxlength = Len(geophone.mask)
```

However if two rows in geophone Tie for longest length both results will be returned. I don't know if this is better or worse for you.

You can also use [ROW_NUMBER](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) in SQL 2005 or later

Comment: "The CROSS APPLY SQL construct or statement is not supported." I'm using MS SQL 2005 Express at my dev server and MS SQL 2005 at deployment.

Comment: @Denis I added a more portable version but please take note of the issue on Ties

Comment: @Denis I think you might be running under a compatibility mode. You can check this by running `sp_dbcmptlevel 'YourDbname'` If its 80 then that means some stuff in SQL 2005 won't work.

Comment: "The current compatibility level is 90."

Comment: @Denis I just tested this and it worked fine on SQL 2005 Express (even with compatibility set to 80). So I don't think you're using Express but rather Compact Edition. Please try `SELECT  SERVERPROPERTY ('edition')` to confirm.

Comment: I investigated this matter and it turned out to be error of Visual Studio SQL editor, not MS SQL Server. CROSS APPLY works as expected if I ignore it. Thank you very much for your efforts.

Comment: Wished to give you small gift for your help but didn't find any way to sent PM or email here.....

Comment: @Denis that's very nice but the Upvote and answer accept are plenty

Answer (score 0):

You can remove duplicate results by using the DISTINCT keyword. However, only use this keyword your logic is actually sound, and not to *hack* your results.  Meaning that, you are only receiving duplicate results because there is some error in your joining logic.  If it's valid to have more than one result, in your case, for a name, then it's valid use.

```
SELECT DISTINCT TOP (5000) 
   Users.Login, 
   Users.Phone, 
   GeoPhone.Region, 
   LEN(GeoPhone.Mask) AS MaskLen
FROM Users 
   INNER JOIN GeoPhone ON LEFT(Users.Phone, LEN(GeoPhone.Mask)) = GeoPhone.Mask
ORDER BY Users.Login, MaskLen DESC
```

Comment: I don't think this meets the OP's "for each by longest matched Mask." requirement

Answer (score 0):

```
select top (5000) 
    users.login, 
    users.phone, 
    geophone.region, 
    max(len(geophone.mask)) as masklen
from   users 
inner join geophone on left(users.phone, len(geophone.mask)) = geophone.mask
group by users.login, users.phone, geophone.region
order by users.login, masklen desc
```

Comment: I tried this before I posted first question and this does not work for me because JOIN returns different Login-Phone-Region pairs for the same login and GROUP BY does not filter this out.